# encoding specification is needed when downloading an image through java socket?

Tags: java, sockets, character-encoding, jpeg

This program should download the specified image from flicker. It's a homework question, i have to use socket. My program successfully makes the http request and receives the response. I eliminate headers and write bytes to a jpg file. But when i want to open it with an image viewer program, it says:

> Error interpreting JPEG image file(Improper call to JPEG library in
>   state 200

So i downloaded the image separetly and opened in a text editor, it seems like some parts of it is not converted.

original file:

> \FF\D8\FF\E0\00JFIF\00\00\00\00\00\00\FF\E2\A0ICC_PROFILE

downloaded file:

> ï¿œï¿œï¿œï¿œ\00JFIF\00\00\00\00\00\00ï¿œï¿œï¿œICC_PROFILE

Is this about character-encoding? if it is, how should i specify encoding? Or what should i do to get jpeg file truly?

```
public class ImageReceiver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String imglink = "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1495/26290635781_138da3fed8_m.jpg";
    String flicker = "farm2.staticflickr.com";

    Socket socket = null;
    DataOutputStream out;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(flicker, 80);
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        out.writeBytes("GET "+ imglink +" HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        out.writeBytes("Host: "+ flicker +":80\r\n\r\n");
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DataInputStream in = null;
    OutputStream output = null;

    try {
        in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        output = new FileOutputStream("chair.txt");

        System.out.println("input connection is established");

        byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
        int length;    
        boolean eohFound = false;

        while ((length = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            if(!eohFound){
                String string = new String(bytes, 0, length);
                int indexOfEOH = string.indexOf("\r\n\r\n");
                if(indexOfEOH != -1) {
                    System.out.println("index: " + indexOfEOH);
                    length = length - indexOfEOH - 4;
                    System.out.println(length);
                    bytes = string.substring(indexOfEOH + 4).getBytes();
                    eohFound = true;
                } else {
                    length = 0;
                }
            }
            output.write(bytes, 0, length);
            output.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


    try {
        in.close();
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Image is downloaded");

}
```

}

Comment: You can't assume the entire `\r\n\r\n` sequence arrives in a single read, and you certainly can't use `String` as a container for binary data. I would read all the header lines first and then start the copy loop.

Comment: When i print indexOfEOH and length(if you run the code, it prints them), it seems ok to me. I mean it founds the index. Otherwise it should never get in the inner if, right? How should i read header lines to make sure that i arrive to \r\n\r\n?

Comment: With `DataInputStream.readLine()`, and yes I know it's deprecated.

Comment: You're right, it's worked! Thanks a lot, you saved me at last moment :)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of EJP, i rewrote my code. Here only modified part. I readLine() till i get the new line, then i read as bytes and write to file:

```
    try {
        in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        output = new FileOutputStream("chair.jpg");

        byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        String inputLine;

        //Get rid of headers...
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            if(inputLine.equals(""))
                break;
        }


        while ((length = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            output.write(bytes, 0, length);
            output.flush();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```